# Ropsten Blockchain Size on Disk December 2019?

Tags: blockchain, parity, synchronization, ropsten

Hello what is the size of the Ropsten Blockchain, on disk, using Parity with full trace on?

(Info required to provision a VPS).

Answer (score 4):

I think it is 43 GB as of December 26. (but don't nail me on that)

If you buy a VPS you should definitely buy one that exceeds this number with easy. (or upgrade capacity later on)